# Getting data when Expiry date in less than today's date + 270 or whatever

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table called ResidencyDetails with columns: EmpNo,ResIssueDate,ResExpiryDate.

What i want is to get data where ResExpiryDate is less than Today's Date + 270 or +180 in a datagridview.

```
con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select Case EmpNo,ResExpiryDate from ResidencyDetails where ResExpiryDate < '" & date + 270 & "'", con)
    Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "ResidencyDetails")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("ResidencyDetails").DefaultView
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**`dateadd(datepart, number, date)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function with `getdate()`.

```
select 
    EmpNo
  , ResExpiryDate 
from ResidencyDetails 
where ResExpiryDate < dateadd(day,270,getdate())
```